# OL3 Draw freehand polygon or linestring on mobile or tablets

Tags: javascript, mobile, gis, openlayers-3

i have added the draw interaction to draw free hand polygon by default freehandCondition is SHIFT key but how can we draw if the map is opened in Mobile and Tablets.

```
drawOptions.type = 'Polygon'; 
this.draw = new ol.interaction.Draw(drawOptions);
this.draw.on('drawend', lang.hitch(this, "drawEnd"));
```

How can we draw? is their any other condition i can give?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to suspend drag pan and enable free-hand drawing in OL3.  Here is one way to set the freeHandCondition (where the variable shapeGeom is Point, LineString or Polygon):

```
function drawInteraction() {
        if (shapeGeom == 'Point') {
            draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
                features: drawfeature,
                type: shapeGeom,
          })
        } else {
            draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
                features: drawfeature,
                type: shapeGeom,
                freehandCondition: ol.events.condition.always,
                condition: ol.events.condition.never,
            })
        }
        map.addInteraction(draw);
    }
```

When you start the draw action, suspend DragPan.

```
map.getInteractions().forEach(function(interaction) {
        if (interaction instanceof ol.interaction.DragPan) {
            interaction.setActive(false);
        }
    }, this);
```

Then, restore DragPan when the feature has been drawn.

```
draw.on('drawend', function(event){
        map.addInteraction(new ol.interaction.DragPan)});
```

OL3's API docs have information for both the [freeHandCondition](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.14.2/apidoc/ol.interaction.Draw.html) and [DragPan](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.14.2/apidoc/ol.interaction.DragPan.html) elements with these links.